# Multilevel CTE Expression slows the execution (Reposted with changes)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

In SQL Server, I have a table-valued function which contains a multi-level CTE as shown in the code here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDataset_Test]
(@XMLBlock XML, @Id INT)
RETURNS 
@tempTable TABLE 
            (
                methodID INT,
                [Id] INT,
                SavingMessage varchar(50)
            )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ObjectID INT = 2;
DECLARE @ExchangeRate INT = 2;
DECLARE @Cond INT = 1;

DECLARE @Param1 varchar(50) = 'name1';
DECLARE @Param2 varchar(50) = 'name2';

    WITH CTE AS 
    ( 
        SELECT   
            Col1,
            con,
            DiscountLine,
            tempNumber,
            ItemCostExVAT,
            Quantity,
            SomeValue,
            methodID,
            VATAmount,
            SubTypeID,
            Line,
            VATMultiplier,
            ROUND(dbo.GetAmountCustomFunction(COALESCE(Id, AnotherId),  COALESCE(Price, PriceValue)), 2) As [Amount]
        FROM     
            dbo.GetObject(@Id, @ObjectID, @ParameterBlock) AS BC
                            
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.fnPrices(@ID, @CurrencyID) BPD ON BPD.Id = BC.productid
    ),
    CTE1 AS 
    ( 
        SELECT   
             *,
             CASE WHEN con = 0 THEN Quantity ELSE 1 END AS Quantity
         FROM     
             CTE
         WHERE
             1 = SomeValue
    ),
    CTE2 AS 
    (
        Select *,       
            MIN(CASE WHEN DiscountLine=1 THEN 1 ELSE 20 END) over (PARTITION by tempNumber) As StockControlled,
            SUM(ItemCostExVAT * Quantity) OVER ( PARTITION BY tempNumber ) AS tempCost ,                     
                        
            ROUND(CASE 
                    WHEN methodID = 8 THEN DiscValue
                    WHEN methodID = 2 THEN END ,
                DicsValue,VATAmount),2) AS AmountExVAT                                                        
               
                    From CTE1
   ),
   CTE3  
   (
       SELECT  
           *,
           ROUND(CASE 
                     WHEN SubTypeID = 1 AND Line = 1 THEN  -1 * AmountExVAT
                     ELSE 20
                 END, 2) PriceExVAT
       FROM    
           CTE2
   ),
   CTE4 
   (
       SELECT 
           *, 
           ROUND(@ExchangeRate * CASE WHEN @Cond = 1 THEN AmountExVAT * VATMultiplier ELSE 20 END, 2) CashBack
       FROM 
           CTE3
   ),
   CTE5 
   (
       SELECT 
           *,
           dbo.FormatMessage(@Param1, @Param2) AS SavingMessage
       FROM
           CTE4
   )
   INSERT INTO @tempTable 
       SELECT 
           methodID, [Id], SavingMessage
       FROM 
           CTE5

   RETURN 
END
```

In above query because of multi-level CTE and table value parameter I can think that its trying to query recursively and taking more execution time.

I know that we cannot use temporary table as function parameter, is there any alternative of this or can I use temporary table by any way in function?

Or can I make some changes in CTE to improve my T-SQL function query execution time?

Comment: I think it was mentioned in your other question that user-defined functions are a performance killer.  It is not clear that the CTEs have anything to do with the poor performance.  If they do, you could probably radically simplify the query to illustrate the performance problem.

Comment: It's not UDFs, @GordonLinoff, it's specifically Multi Line TVFs, which this is. Well written iTVFs can be *very* perfomant. I  suspect the OP also had nested mlTVFs, but they didn't confirm that on the other question.

Comment: Also, don't repost your question, edit the original. It was closed for good reason. Make it on topic and get it reopened.

Comment: @Larnu, I have reposted this question after making changes in Query. Now query should not be giving compilation error.
Here I have tried to duplicate the actual query on database. As I cannot share same query

Comment: As I said, *don't* repost your question. There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69280830/edit) feature which is specifically there so that you can make amendments to your question.

Comment: And you STILL have syntax errors. In CTE (and others), you use an aggregate (round) but there is no GROUP BY clause. Your obfuscation attempt has created errors and confusion and serves no one.  Without much more detailed information, it is impossible to make useful suggestions.